# Difference between initialized controllers and FXML linked controllers?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Until recently I didn't know you could set controllers with `fx:controller` in the `FXML` file so I have relied on `FXMLLoader's` `setController` to manage linking.

So, is there any reason to use one over another like a particular case where the `overrideable initialize()` method would be useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no functional difference between the two methods of setting a controller for an fxml file. However, in terms of when to use which there is a slight distinction.

1. If your controller doesn't need any external objects to initialize its state before calling its own `initialize()`, in other words your controller class has a `no-arg constructor` (OR you call `FXMLLoader`'s `setControllerFactory()` and provide it with implementation of how the controller should be initialized) and is fully manageable by `FXMLLoader`, then you go for the `fx:controller` and set it in the fxml file itself. `FXMLLoader` will load the controller and call its `initialize()` if there is such method. This is the default way of linking a controller and fxml file.
2. If you controller has a constructor with `at least 1 argument` or in the controller's `initialize()` it requires access to fields which must be initialized externally (not within the controller class), then you manually manage the controller. You create an instance of it, like with any other Java class, initialize what is required and only then call `setController()` to link your controller with the fxml file. This technique is typically used with custom controllers

For more details please have a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components

Comment: You can actually use any controller with fx:controller, as long as you set a controller factory on the FXMLLoader. It then becomes the responsibility of the factory to instantiate controller classes. No parameterless constructor required.