# JavaFX using initialized controllers and FXML linked controllers in same application

Tags: javafx, controller, fxml

Regarding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171352/difference-between-initialized-controllers-and-fxml-linked-controllers) question I would like to know if it is ok to use both methods for different controllers in the same application.

This is, if a controller is not to be accessed externally I would use the fx:controller and if it needs to be accessed externally I would use the setController() method.

Comment: Of course you can use the one you prefer for each distinct controller (even if it is always better to try keeping the same approach for the entire application for a better understanding).

Comment: There's nothing really wrong with this. However you need to be aware of the fact that you won't be able to reuse the same code both approaches. Depending on your needs using a `controllerFactory` that does dependency injection or something similar could be a way that does not have this issue.

Comment: So, in case I had to use a unique method I understand the way to go is the setController one as this option allows the controller to be accessed externally. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can access all the controller methods using either method, provided the methods are `public` (or any valid appropriate accessor).

Using `FXMLLoader::setController()` method is useful when your controller has non-default constructor. This is covered in the StackOverflow post you mentioned.

If you have set a controller class via `fx:controller`, you can retrieve the controller instance via `FXMLLoader::getController()`, and you can call any method that that controller has using that instance.

Comment: I have found, nonetheless, a possible situation where fx:controller is needed always. Please correct me if I´m wrong: If I have a fxml with nested tabs and each tab has a controller I would need to have the specific fx:controller written in every fxml of each tab. If not, when loading the main fxml I would get an error. Is this correct?

Comment: @user6127833 Setting controller via FXML is the easier way when you have a plain controller. When you nest FXML in a FXML, then you would have to load separate FXML file for each tab. So again, there is nothing special - you either set controllers in in `FXMLLoader` or you set them in the FXML files.